# How to decode string that contains encoded Json using Apache Flink SQL?

Tags: json, apache-flink, filebeat, flink-sql

Using Flink 1.10

My application logs are written as Json and I use Filebeat to tail the log files and push them to Kafka. Filebeat itself wraps the logs in its own Json. So my logs are encoded as  strings in Filbeat's "message" property.

**Example:** `{ "@timestamp": "2021-11-22...", "message": "{\"someProperty\":\"someValue\"}" }`

Is there a way to tell Flink SQL to decode the field into a Json object?

I'm guessing a UDF needs to be created, there's no existing functionality?

Comment: Some JSON functions will probably be added in Flink 1.15. Until then you’ll need to use a UDF.

Answer (score 0):

As David pointed out in the comments, Flink 1.15 will add several built-in JSON functions. However, two of them are already available in Flink 1.14. If you want to extract a specific scalar value, like `someProperty`, you can use

```
JSON_VALUE(input, 'lax $.message.someProperty')
```